# I am using object-to-formdata to save form input,images,video in database.It's not working for Iphone users

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

> ## My code for form input.

```
 validateForm: function (scope) {
        this.$validator.validateAll(scope).then(result => {
            if (result) {
                this.newProductData.brand = this.step2.brand;
                this.newProductData.condition = this.step3.condition;
                this.newProductData.desc = this.step2.desc;
                this.newProductData.name = this.step2.name;
                this.newProductData.qty = this.step2.qty;
                this.newProductData.height = this.step3.height;
                this.newProductData.width = this.step3.width;
                this.newProductData.depth = this.step3.depth;
                this.newProductData.weight = this.step3.weight;
                this.newProductData.images = this.images;

                this.loader = true;
                alert('before formdata');
                let formData = objectToFormData(this.newProductData);
               d);
                formData.append('video',this.formData.get('video'));

                axios.post('/user/dashboard/products/new',formData, {emulateJSON: true}).then(response=>{
                    if(response.data.status === 'success'){
                        //this.addVideoImage(response.data.product_id);
                        Vue.toasted.success(response.data.message, {
                            position: 'top-center',
                            duration: 3000
                        });
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            window.location.href = '/user/dashboard/products';
                        }, 1000);
                    }else{
                        this.loader = false;
                        Vue.toasted.error('Something went wrong!', {
                            position: 'top-center',
                            duration: 3000
                        })
                    }
                });
```

> After taking formdata as an object,while trying to append the video file into the formDate object,it's not working.
>
> ## Issue only for Iphone users.
>
> ## Any suggesstions or any other library would be very helpfull.Thank you

Comment: Could you show me an error message from the iPhone?

Comment: @MaxLyashuk:I ts shows no error.You can see **this.loader** variable.This variable is always true after submitting.If i comment : **formdata.append()**.then its working fine in all devices.I mean to say i couldn't upload video file in **Iphone**.